# Live Tiles - staying connected

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, live-tile

Live tiles are able to receive push notifications without the associated metro app needing to be running.

However I believe that the app must have run at least once in order for the app to acquire a notification channel and subscribe to a notification server, passing the channel to the server.

My question is -

What happens if the server cuts off the client? If the user turns off their computer I presume the server would start receiving delivery failure errors. The server might then cut off the client.

But what happens when the user turns their computer back on? Is the tile now disconnected until the user starts the app again and it resubscribes with the server for notifications?

Or is there a way for the tile to resubscribe automatically on start up without the app having to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The push notifications are not sent directly to the client; they're sent via the Windows Notification service in the cloud. This means your service will be able to just send them. The WNS service will do the right thing with notifications when the machine comes out of sleep / reconnects to the network.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh913756.aspx has a overview of the service side of notifications.

It's important to note that the tile channel expires after 30 days, and will need to be (programmatically) renewed. The guidance is that you should renew when the app runs to make sure it doesn't expire.

The only thing I can't seem to locate in the documentation is how many push notifications are queued on the client -  I suspect that for a given tag notification, only one is kept.

Maybe another way to think about this is with the bad notification -- e.g a "new items" count. If you push this number while the device is disconnect from the network (off, driven over etc), then your service will succeed in sending the notification, and when that machine reconnects, it will seamlessly see the badge update.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle that in your code that when your clients from the server went offline then you should remove them and disconnect them, the client side will only receive the cached values in the live tiles.

If they went back on, then you should also handle it in your server side to push the new notification data.

Just a quick tip: If you are using WCF as your service, you might want to check the [Announcement Service Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.announcementservice.aspx) there you can handle your clients online/offline scenarios.